# KVM - Modify from IDE to VirtIO

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virt-manager, virtio

I imported a CentOS 7 guest from XenServer to KVM.

After importing it into KVM the disk bus in use is the IDE.

**I need to change the disk bus from IDE to VirtIO because VirtIO has better performance.**

I have seen many forums... No solution so far... =[

How can I do this?

**NOTE:** When I change disk settings in Virtual Machine Manager (virt-manager) the grub menu is displayed, but the guest OS does not start.

[image: virt-manager]

Comment: Why doesn't it start?

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is precisely my question ... The grub menu is displayed, but the OS does not start.

Comment: What is the grub command line you executed? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I simply choose the first option from the grub menu when the machine starts.

Comment: OK, but what is it running? You need to actually go in and look at it.

Comment: Where can I get the information you need?

Comment: You can select the grub menu entry, and press `e`.